# Avoid round when getting coordinates from raster file

Tags: r, coordinates, rounding, floating-accuracy, geo

I'm converting a raster into points to make some calculations. The raster points have a 0.5 precission and when I try to get the coordinate of a point inside the point matrix, R decide to round just Y coordinate as you can see in the example below.

```
rasterdir <- ".../raster1.tif"
r <- raster(rasterdir)
rp <- rasterToPoints(r)
rp1 <- rp[1, ]

> rp[1, ]

          x           y     raster1 
 534001.500 4750000.500     337.334
```

.

```
rp1x <- rp[1, 1]

> rp1x

       x 
534001.5
```

.

```
rp1y <- rp[1, 2]

> rp1y

      y 
4750001
```

Any suggestions to keep that Y in 4750000.5 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading numbers in the console would be very difficult if all decimals were always shown. So, by default, R does not do that

```
x <- 12.000005
x
#[1] 12
```

But you can force showing then in a number of ways. E.g.

```
sprintf("%.10f", x)
#[1] "12.0000050000"
```

Or

```
options(digits=10)
x
#[1] 12.000005
```